# Run multiple commands in serial and make sure all commands run

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I want to run a series of unix commands, one after another. If any of these commands dies for whatever reason, subsequent commands should continue to run.

For instance, I have 3 commands called "setup", "long-running-job" and "teardown". If "long-running-job" finishes with whatever exit code, or dies unexpectedly, I want to make sure "teardown" gets run in any case.

Simply concatenating all commands with semicolons doesn't seem to work. I tried running `touch test.txt; ping localhost; rm test.txt` in macOS Terminal, closed the terminal tab while it's running, and found that the "test.text" didn't get removed.

Comment: Closing the terminal isn't the same as the command failing to run.  If you want to run things even when you aren't there you can put them in the background.

Comment: Certainly best to put it in a script, but you can probably do `trap 'rm test.txt' 0; ping localhost` (assuming bash: for other shells you may need to be more specific about the signals you want to catch).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make sure that even if your interactive window closes that your commands keep going and that all your command happen sequentially in the order you specify then use the method in this answer:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/47231

Basically for the command line in your question

```
nohup sh -c 'touch test.txt; ping localhost; rm test.txt'
```

That means the hang up signal sent by closing the terminal is ignored.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried [GNU parallel](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/)? Seems like the ideal tool for your needs.

```
$> parallel ::: setup long-running-job teardown
```

Parallel comes with tons of options to control halts, failures, jumps, retries, etc. See the manual and the tutorial for examples.

Comment: Huh?  The OP specifically wants the commands to run serially.

Comment: Anyone reading @triplee comment might make the same mistake. You need to see the manual to figure out which ones you want to run manually and which ones serially. You control each job and the level of parallelism you want.

Comment: If you can edit your answer to clarify this, I will be able to retract my downvote.  Thanks in advance, and sorry for jumping the gun.

Comment: I would if that alone were to be enough to improve reading comprehension.